# Contiguous ranges from timestamped multi-indexed data batches in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

There are a number of related questions on this (e.g. [Collating timestamped events into date ranges with pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20466590/13352657)), but none quite seem to cover this use case and I'm struggling to cover the gap...

I have *multiple batch dataframes* of records (because the combined dataset is bigger than available memory) with a MultiIndex starting with a datetime, and then other dimensions which identify each record's subject - like this:

```
                                          | price   available
timestamp               item    location  |
------------------------------------------+------------------
2020-01-01 01:00:00     itemA   loc1      |  21.7        True
2020-01-01 02:00:00     itemA   loc1      |  25.8        True
2020-01-01 03:00:00     itemA   loc1      |  36.1        True
2020-01-01 05:00:00     itemA   loc1      |  41.9       False
2020-01-01 11:00:00     itemB   loc1      | 103.8        True
2020-01-01 12:00:00     itemB   loc1      | 103.8        True
```

The datetimes have already been binned and aligned to the required granularity, which could be daily, 15-minutely, or hourly as shown above.

I'd like to build up the list of **contiguous time-ranges covered** at this granularity as batches arrive. The result might look something like the below:

```
                  |               start                     end
item    location  |
------------------+--------------------------------------------
itemA   loc1      | 2020-01-01 01:00:00     2020-01-01 03:00:00
itemA   loc1      | 2020-01-01 05:00:00     2020-01-01 05:00:00
itemB   loc1      | 2020-01-01 11:00:00     2020-01-01 12:00:00
```

...but this output example makes some assumptions I'm not actually tied to:

- Which output columns are indexes vs fields? Doesn't really matter
- Either the `start` or the `end` date could be offset by one interval if that makes implementation easier... e.g. if all the `end` values were incremented by 1hr in this case.

What's the most appropriate/resource-efficient way to go about this in Pandas?

My current thought is to:

- Create a copy df/series with the [timestamp index shifted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50867722/13352657) by one time step forwards, self-join and use `isna()` to identify records which are a `start`
- Do the same to identify records which are an `end`
- Combine these (maybe using something like merge_asof?) to get the contiguous ranges contained in the batch
- Do another layer of joins/manipulation to update the global list by extending any previously detected ranges and combining ranges if new data bridges between previously separate sets

...But it starts to seem like a lot of process steps for something which feels like a pretty standard requirement.

Does anybody know of a good solution/pattern to apply here? Thanks!

**Edit:** Try to clarify that representation of the output timestamps could be a little different and still fine.

Comment: Can you explain how do you get `start` and `end` values? since one entry of your desired output has the same `start` and `end` `2020-01-01 05:00:00     2020-01-01 05:00:00`. It is a bit confusing.

Comment: Tried to make it a little clearer with the edit - does that help? Would be fine if that end example was `06:00:00`, so long as the column was *consistently* +1 increment after the last record :-)